# Which theory/model explains electrons movement inside a transmitting antenna?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, quantum-electrodynamics, antennas

I have an understanding of electrical circuits, however I am very interested to know more about electromagnetic waves radiation.

In particular I want to know how an oscillating voltage causes the electrons move inside a conductive antenna.
Voltage is only a difference in electrical potential in our local circuit, it is only difference between electrical potential of two nets (ex ANT and GND) so how the ANT net can itself cause movements of electrons inside an antenna? (because in some circuits the antenna is only connected to ANT.)

I want to know which physics model explains this phenomenon? as far as I know circuit theory doesn't explain this behavior. so It should be something else.

I know there are some formulas to model electromagnetic radiation, however I want to build an intuition around this, I don't need formulas to solve problems.

Also I know that speed of the light has relation to design of the antenna, so I think the theory should include speed of the light as well.

I prefer to not get very deep in physic subjects, so I am looking for the most higher level theory/model which is able to fully explain this :)

Comment: There is electrostatic field in the emitting antenna due to the circuit, this is quantified by voltage on the antenna input. This electrostatic field is most of the force that drives current in the antenna. The rest is induced electric field from the circuit (but this is usually localized to components and very weak far from them) and induced electric field from the antenna itself, which opposes the driving force and is the source of the radiation damping in the antenna.

Comment: The field in the antenna is not static, it is oscillating. It is that oscillating field that accelerates electrons in the conductor back and forth leading to the antenna radiating.

Comment: *Voltage is only a difference in electrical potential.* Why do you say “only”? Differences in potential from place to place mean there is an electric field and thus forces on charged particles. Negative charges like electrons move from places with lower potential to places with higher potential.

Comment: @Ghoster I said that since it is not a general state for a place, it is relative to other places, its something like a measure which is local ( not sure about the word "local" ) to that circuit, so how oscillations in that causes flow of electrons in an open ended wire (antenna).

Comment: Do you understand that $\mathbf E=-\nabla\phi$?

Comment: @Ghoster No, should I learn about it ?

Comment: Yes, it’s fundamental to understanding the physical significance of electric potential.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the part you are missing.

The high-frequency AC current in an antenna is changing so quickly that the current at the center of a dipole can be *completely different* from the current at the distant ends of the dipole, and the same for the voltage along the length of the dipole wires.

For a center-fed, *resonant* (1/2-wave) dipole, the current at the ends of the dipole wires is almost zero but is at a maximum at the center (feed point) of the dipole. The voltage at the ends of the dipole wires is simultaneously at a maximum while it is at a minimum at the feed point.

This sort of unusual behavior (!) happens because the antenna length is of order ~the wavelength of the RF signal being fed into the antenna.

Answer (score 0):

You need to study “antenna theory”. In short the signal is high frequency so a lot of assumptions from dc/lumped element circuit models go out the door. You can model the antenna as a series of capacitors and inductors and this might get you a little closer. But these models will always fail to model radiative energy emission. For that I think you need full 3d electromagnetic modeling. I guess some codes can simulate this numerically.